# Powershell import-csv $variable properly is null

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a weird issues with Powershell Version 2.0.

The following works on newer versions but its not working as expected on this version. Any help is appreciated.

```
$DB = Import-Csv -Path "$($path)\DBExtrat.csv"
```

which is fine.
Headers in DBExtrat.csv (`'hostname','hostip','name','type'`)
all 4 headers are reorganized and show up if i run

```
$DB
```

But if I try
`$DB.name` or `$DB.hostname` it returns noting. I need to be able to call it like this because my whole logic is tied to those specific variables names.

I've already tried adding the `-header` option:

```
$DB = Import-Csv -Path "$($path)\DBExtrat.csv" -Header 'hostname','hostip','name','type'
```

but it doesn't work and also creates unnecessary extra row with header data.

Comment: can you run a `$DB | Get-Member` and seeing what NoteProperty it returns for your Column Names?

Comment: TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name             MemberType   Definition
----             ----------   ----------
Equals           Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode      Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType          Method       type GetType()
ToString         Method       string ToString()
hostip           NoteProperty System.String hostip=1.1.1.1
hostname         NoteProperty System.String hostname=bla.bla
name             NoteProperty System.String name=Default
type             NoteProperty System.String type=I

Comment: Does piping it make any difference? `| select-object name`

Comment: Hi Abraham, Thanks for the help this works  | select-object name or any other header value. I don't understand why. Do you think there is a way to still get it to work with $DB.name? Thank you again

Comment: @Evo Are you using PowerShell 2.0? Upgrade. Property Enumeration was introduced in 3.0 or 4.0

Comment: Thanks Mathias, yes it's powershell 2.0 but I can't upgrade. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an expression such as `$DB.name`, you're trying to get the `name` property values of *all elements* of collection `$DB`, by performing the property access on the *collection as a whole*.

This feature is called **[member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)**, and it is **only available in PowerShell v3+**.

The **PowerShell v2 equivalent** requires use of either [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) or [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

```sh
# Note the use of -ExpandProperty to ensure that only the property *value*
# is returned (without it, you get a *custom object* with a 'name' property).
$DB | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name

# Slower alternative, but can provide more flexibility
$DB | ForEach-Object { $_.name }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend going with @mklement0 answer; short and simple. Alternatively, going off the question you asked in the comments, you may try working with a custom object and seeing if the below works.

```
$import = Import-Csv -Path "$($path)\DBExtrat.csv"
$Object = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    'hostname' = $import | Select-Object -ExpandProperty hostname
    'hostip'   = $import | Select-Object -ExpandProperty hostip
    'name'     = $import | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
    'type'     = $import | Select-Object -ExpandProperty type   
}
    "$Object.hostname - $Object.hostip"
```